# Optimization of volume of a container

Tags: calculus, optimization

A garbage container is to be constructed out of 400 ft2 of material. The vessel will have a square base and an
open top. Find the width and the height of the container that maximize its capacity and give the maximum
capacity? Round your answers to 3 decimal places.

im confused about this problem. It says is it constructed out of 400sqft of material. So does that mean i need to use the Surface area formula? The answer is asking for the length width and volume. so this is making me think that i need to use the the volume formula.. can someone help me through this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use both

$$  V(x,h) = x^2h $$

$$SA = x^2 + 4xh = 400 $$

$$ \implies h = \frac{400-x^2}{4x}$$

Plug that into $V$ getting

$$ V(x) = \frac 14 x(400-x^2)  $$

Can you take it from there ?

Comment: Cool, yes i figured it out. thank you for the help. these optimization problems confuse me sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the point is to maximize the final volume $V$ of the container

e.g. if you use all the material for the base you obtain $V=0$

then you have to write down a formula for the volume as a function depending by a single unknown/variable and then maximize this function by setting  its derivative equal to zero